# SQLite how to overwrite same data

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am working on an android project, basicli I have some x,y coordinates in my sqlite but when I add a new data I want to check the data and if there is same data overwrite it.

```
public void DBCreate(){
    SQLITEDATABASE = openOrCreateDatabase("LatLongDatabase", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    SQLITEDATABASE.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, mCurrentLocationLAT VARCHAR,mCurrentLocationLONG VARCHAR);");
}

public void SubmitData2SQLiteDB(){


        SQLiteQuery = "INSERT INTO myTable (mCurrentLocationLAT, mCurrentLocationLONG) VALUES('"+mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()+"','"+mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()+"');";
        SQLITEDATABASE.execSQL(SQLiteQuery);

        Toast.makeText(CampaignActivity.this,"OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

Comment: If data is the same, why update? you just need to skip the insert, right?

Comment: what is the primary key on your `myTable` ?

Comment: Look into `REPLACE`

Comment: @Vasya You are right it is possible.

Comment: How can I ignore the same data ?

Comment: Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `UPDATE` query to update the row with `PRIMARY_KEY` if data exists or `INSERT` new row.

Since your table have a `PRIMARY_KEY` as `id`, you can check if row exists as below.

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE id='ROW_ID');
```

If above query returns 1, then data exists, and you need to use `UPDATE` query as below, else use `INSERT` query.

```
UPDATE myTable SET mCurrentLocationLAT=value1, mCurrentLocationLONG=value2 WHERE id='ROW_ID';
```

Comment: Does it have to be like this ?

SQLiteQuery = "UPDATE  INTO myTable32 (mCurrentLocationLAT, mCurrentLocationLONG) VALUES('"+mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()+"','"+mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()+"');";

Comment: I am trying for two days and can not do it, could you please fix my code and write :(

Comment: You cannot change INSERT into UPDATE and try to run the SQL. Check https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp for more about UPDATE statements.

Comment: Yes I changed it but it throws this error "SQL(query) error or missing database"

Comment: Can you help me please urgently I can not do

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has an INSERT OR REPLACE statement which can be shortened just to REPLACE which will insert a new row if it doesn't exist, or replace (delete then insert) a row if it does exist.  Read the docs to learn about primary key constraints and how to handle them.

```
REPLACE INTO positions (title, min_salary)
VALUES
 ('Full Stack Developer', 140000);
```

Comment: I tried it but writes the same data again and again.

Comment: Like I said, it depends on how the primary key is defined and/or any other indexes with a unique key constraint.  But this probably isn't what you want anyway.

Comment: I have the primary key but REPLACE overwrites